# Which type of LEGO bricks would be compatible with the Mega Bloks Blind Bag Figures?

Tags: building, compatibility, clone-brands

My husband collects the Marvel figures which come in the Mega Bloks blind bags. His birthday is coming up and I'd like to build him a display for his Marvel figures. I'd strongly prefer to use LEGO in order to build this display. I've read that certain types of Mega Bloks are compatible with certain types of LEGO bricks. (I will most likely have to purchase online so I won't be able to compare size in person before purchasing.)

How can I make sure that the type of LEGO I am buying will fit the foot holes of the Mega Bloks Marvel figures?

Comment: Hi Suzy, if you take a look at [this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/753/56) you'll see a few examples of how they work together.

Answer (score 4):

Mega blocks can stand on any Lego plate just as good as Lego figures. This is demonstrated in this battle scene between Lego and Mega Blocks figures:

[mega bloks halo vs. lego star wars clones](http://youtu.be/KgIf1n0MY38)

<sup>Before you play this, I advice you to turn down the sound a bit...</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use any LEGO plates with the mega bloks figures. In the blind packs they stay on the mega bloks doublebricks, that are fully compatible with LEGO doublebricks. So you could take any set pack as you want. (some time ago i have used lego collectable minifigures stand with megabloks figures, it was usable, but i think they weren't standing too tight in there).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for some LEGO Bricks to build up a scene, then any of the standard LEGO sets or boxes of bricks would fit the figures - certainly the holes in the feet will fit the LEGO studs quite nicely, and the feet are spaced correctly to fit.

You could also take a look at the [Marvel Super Hero range](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Marvel-Super-Heroes-ByTheme) that LEGO offer which include a rather large diorama set [6868 Hulk's Helicarrier Breakout](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=6868-1).

Note that the larger figures on the LEGO Shop page aren't compatible with the Megabloks figures, as they're over 7 inches tall.