# Mega Bloks vs LEGO bases

Tags: compatibility, 3rd-party

Are Mega Bloks compatible with LEGO bases? Do they sell larger LEGO bases for them? I am making a table but want to use the correct base.

Comment: Hi Charlene - you might find "[In what ways are LEGO and MegaBloks Incompatible?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/753/56)" useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

LEGO Bases work with Mega Bloks, as the bricks are the same dimensions. However, certain Mega Bloks pieces, like specialized items and weapons, may not fit optimally with LEGO minifigures.

Certain bricks (including the maxi and DUPLO-sized bricks) are on a larger scale. They produce bricks that will work with DUPLO plates and such. This is probably the most produced size.